# What is causing this artifact, when exporting from blender to ue4 as fbx?

Tags: export, .fbx, artifacts, unreal-engine

Im new to blender and i literally have no clue, what is causing this problem :c[image: Blender]

[image: Unreal Engine]

Comment: It looks like it could be z-fighting (an issue where multiple textures are close to each other so the camera doesn't know which one to render) Check the model in blender to make sure there are no faces stacked on-top of each other or close to overlapping. If you are unsure I would advice searching for a more in depth explanation of z-fighting it's causes and how to avoid and/or fix them.

Comment: i will make sure to check this out, thank you :D